# Boto3 List all the rules in each aws security group

Tags: boto3

To get all group I used:

```
groups = list(ec2.security_groups.all())
```

Then:

```
rules = []
for grp in groups:
   sgid =  grp.group_id
   try:
       response = ec2_client.describe_security_groups(GroupIds=[sgid])
       rules.append(response)
   except ClientError as e:
       print(e)
```

I'm left with a nasty json to parse :-(.

Comment: Whats question here?

Answer (score 5):

Following is one of the many ways to obtain your desired output.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-south-1')
response = ec2.describe_security_groups()
for i in response['SecurityGroups']:
    print("Security Group Name: " + i['GroupName'])
    print("the Egress rules are as follows: ")
    for j in i['IpPermissionsEgress']:
        print("IP Protocol: " + j['IpProtocol'])
        for k in j['IpRanges']:
            print("IP Ranges: " + k['CidrIp'])
    print("The Ingress rules are as follows: ")
    for j in i['IpPermissions']:
        print("IP Protocol: " + j['IpProtocol'])
        try:
            print("PORT: " + str(j['FromPort']))
            for k in j['IpRanges']:
                print("IP Ranges: " + k['CidrIp'])
        except Exception:
            print("No value for ports and ip ranges available for this security group")
            continue
```

Comment: Just heads up, this will likely need to be updated since I got a Keyerror when I ran this code as is. In my case there was keyerror on `'FromPort'` - this can be empty when user selects "All traffic" etc.